# How to increase the sharpness of an image?

Tags: image-processing

I have an image of a molecule (attached png file). The problem is when I reduce the height and width to 20*20 using free-available programs on the web, it becomes very blurred. I would like to know if there is a way to increase the sharpness of the image.[image: molecule]

Comment: what about a simple threshold?

Comment: I think you have a problem. you want to decrease an image of around 45X45 pixels to 20X20 and the difference in pixels between the inner lines and the outer shape is around one pixel so of course when you will downsample the image it will get blurred because there isn't enough resolution to represent the difference between the lines and the shape and i don't think any sharpening will help you.

Answer (score 2):

by using Laplace you can sharpen the image.

you can read http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/laplace_operator/laplace_operator.html

```
Laplacian( src_gray, dst, ddepth, kernel_size, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
```